# Problems Jooma Firefox & Kaspersky: 200 Request has been forbidden by antivirus

Tags: firefox, joomla

I am using Joomla 3.4 with Firefox and Kaspersky Internet Security. I am receiving the error

```
200 Request has been forbidden by antivirus
```

all the time until the buffer is full and Firefox hangs. It happens on my own site and others For example http://forum.joomla.org

If I exit Kasperky that message disappears but is replaced by a JSON syntax error in what looks to be a temporary generated file.
Has anyone else hit this? I have had no solution offered by Kaspersky nor (so for) from joomla.org.

Regards 
Nick

Comment: Yes getting the same, for me its error code: 499 but no solution found so far!

Comment: I did fix it in the end and should have logged the solution.  Now trying to recall.  I think I created a new Firefox profile. It wasn't a Kaspersky problem.  I am now running OK with FF and Kaspersky.  Sorry not to be more helpful.

Comment: Actually for me its some particular type of localhost requests. Its not Joomla but jsp/java pages.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with Kaspersky and Firefox when working on a web development project. (C# ASP not Joomla).

I disabled the Kaspersky add-on for Firefox and disabled "Web Anti-Virus" in Kaspersky.

To disable web anti-virus go to Settings -> Protection and then slide "Web Anti-Virus" off.

I did some extra research: This can also be a result of the "Anti-Banner" feature that can also be disabled under Settings -> Protection.

Comment: Did you disable both Anti-Banner and Web Anti-Virus? Also what version of Kasperksy are you using?